# How to take a photo using Camera in Sencha App?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to take a picture using camera in Sencha Touch 2. Here i have one button 'Take a Picture', when i will press it, camera should start. As i am new to this sencha touch 2, i am unable to figure it out, how to do this?
For this i used the below code:

[Sencha Fiddle Link](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#qlH6u)

Please help me. I do not want to use Phone gap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add device folder of Sencha Library in root directory
and add below code in

```
Ext.require('Ext.device.Camera');
```

and use this code for capture image using camera

```
Ext.device.Camera.capture({
            success: function(image) {
                imageView.setSrc(image);
            },
            quality: 75,
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            destination: 'data'
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But if i am writing the above method, it is not directly opening the camera. For that i wrote the below code:       Ext.device.Camera.capture({
    source: 'camera',
    destination: 'file',

    success: function(url) {
        this.fireEvent('change', this, url);
    },
    failure: function() {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'There was an error when acquiring the picture.');
    },
    scope: this
});

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use purely sencha, then you can check this code:

```
 xtype: 'button',
            handler: function(button, event) {
                Ext.device.Camera.capture({
                    source: 'camera',
                    destination: 'data',

                    success: function(imagedata) {

                        var img = Ext.getCmp('theimage');
                        img.setSrc('data:image/jpeg;base64,' +imagedata);
                    },

                    failure: function() {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'There was an error when acquiring the picture.');
                    },
                    scope: this
                });
```

But if you want to use phonegap camera features, may be you have to change the code. As sencha is giving the default feature to handle the camera, i wish not to go with phonegap.  Hope it will help..