# Camera functionality in Sencha Touch+PhoneGap, {How to access camera by clicking button. & how to replace the default image with the captured image}

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have implemented a **Phone Gap application using Sencha Touch** for *android and iphone*.

in this app

in one of my view(page) **i have a default image and button just under the image**.

The **`button is to access camera feature action`** and the **`default image is is replaced by the captured image.`**

[image]

*`how to access camera by clicking a button. and how to replace the default image with the captured image`*

by browsing i have found the following link,

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.device.Camera

But i did n't know how to hookup this code with my button click action and how to replace the image source

Can any one help me please

My code in my view:

```
{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Camera Page',
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'center',
                    pack: 'center',
                    },


                items: [
                      //Default image it should be replace with the new one

                            {
                            xtype: 'image',
                            src: 'images/Gallery.png',
                            height: 200,
                            left: 200,
                            top: 0,
                            width: 300
                            },

                      //Button to move to the camera feature      
                            {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            id: 'CameraClick',
                            ui: 'action',
                            text: 'Camera',
                            top: 222,
                            left: 200,
                            padding: 20,
                            },

                       ]
        },
```

Comment: [try this answer it will may help you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893707/how-to-take-a-photo-using-camera-in-sencha-app/10899225#10899225

Comment: where we used that code to hook up the button click

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this

```
    {
        id: 'capturedImage',
        xtype: 'image',
        src: 'images/Gallery.png',
        height: 200,
        left: 200,
        top: 0,
        width: 300
    },

    {
        xtype: 'button',
        id: 'CameraClick',  
        ui: 'action',
        text: 'Camera',
        top: 222,
        left: 200,
        padding: 20,
        handler: function(){
            Ext.device.Camera.capture({
                success: function(image) {
                    var imageView = Ext.getCmp('capturedImage');
                    imageView.setSrc(image);
                },                          
                destination: 'camera'
// other options goes here. Use documentation http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.device.Camera-method-capture
            });
        }
    },
```

Comment: when we click the button causes to an error: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Ext.device.Camera')"

Comment: Does you device have the camera ? Try the phonegap API http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

Answer (score -2):

Did you add  requires: ['Ext.device.Camera'] in your file then it should work.